# near " ": syntax error: UPDATE tablename

Tags: sqlite, syntax-error

I use **SQLLite**. My sql code has only one line: UPDATE **loty** and it gives:

> near " ": syntax error: UPDATE loty

Once I overcome this I will proceed with further lines as I want to insert values to a column in loty from another table.
Why this one line of code (UPDATE loty) gives this syntax error?

Comment: `UPDATE loty` by itself is not a complete SQL statement, because it is missing a `SET` clause.  What are you trying to update here?

Comment: this is what I try to achieve: UPDATE loty.destinationairportcode SET loty.destinationairportcode=kody_lotnisk.destinationairportcode
WHERE loty.destination=kody_lotnisk.destination;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never relate the two tables properly.  SQLite does not support update join, but it does support using a correlated subquery in the `SET` clause:

```
UPDATE loty t1
SET destinationairportcode = (SELECT destinationairportc‌​ode FROM kody_lotnisk t2
                              WHERE t1.destination = t2.destination);
```

You never gave us any clear logic regarding whether you want to update every record in the `loty` table, or just certain records.  If the latter, then you can add a `WHERE` clause to the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

You are using incomplete syntax.
The original syntax is:-

```
UPDATE table_name SET field1 = new-value1, field2 = new-value2
[WHERE Clause]
```

Comment: this is what I try to achieve: UPDATE loty.destinationairportcode SET loty.destinationairportcode=kody_lotnisk.destinationairportc‌​ode WHERE loty.destination=kody_lotnisk.destination;

Comment: You can not use join in SQLite for UPDATE directly.